# Run JUnit test only on Linux

Tags: java, junit

I have a basic JUnit test which I want to run only on Linux. How I can skip the test if I build the code on Windows?

For example can I get the OS platform from Java?

Comment: "can I get the OS platform from Java?" how about doing some research before asking a question?

Comment: Please see [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) "Search, and research

...and keep track of what you find. Even if you don't find a useful answer elsewhere on the site, including links to related questions that haven't helped can help others in understanding how your question is different from the rest. " "Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, **and** any **difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself**."

Comment: This shouldn't be marked duplicate. It's asking how to determine OS platform **to skip a JUnit test**

Answer (score 16):

`System.getProperty("os.name")` will give you the name of the OS. You can then use the [`Assume`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html) class to skip a test if the OS is Windows:

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
    Assume.assumeFalse
        (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().startsWith("win"));
    // test logic
}
```

**Edit:**

The modern JUnit Jupiter has a [built-in capability](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-conditional-execution-os) for this with the `@EnableOnOs` and `@DisableOnOs` annotations:

```
@Test
@EnabledOnOs(LINUX)
public void testSomething() {
    // test logic
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `@Before` to bypass all tests contained in the class:

```
@Before
public void beforeMethod()
{
    Assume.assumeFalse(System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().startsWith("win"));
    // rest of the setup
}
```